# Where do you see the result of "#pragma mark" in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

I'm trying to find where I can see the result of `#pragma mark`s in Xcode 4 but can't seem to find it.

The reference [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-and-pragma-mark.html) talks about the grouping in the Function Menu but I can't seem to find this in Xcode 4 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you have the file selected in XCode, in the bar above the editor area (known as the *Jump Bar*), you might see something to the effect of "Project Name > Classes > Filename > No Selection." Click on "No Selection". Your `#pragma mark`s will fill out this area.

Comment: Horribly, pragmas within methods no longer show up in XCode 4. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313492/pragma-mark-not-showing-in-methods-in-xcode-4-0

Comment: Or for shorts, press `CTRL + 6`

Answer (score 10):

You can see it by clicking on "No Selection":

[image: Here]

Answer (score 1):

If you include a `#pragma` mark, it will become more readable.

Thank you. It's very simple but not easy to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Along with pragma entries, Xcode will also display points where a comment begins with "\TODO: "   Great way to leave and find breadcrumbs for follow-up work.